# PHP - Filter objects based on array values inside each object

Tags: php

I have an array of objects, where each object contains an array for an attribute

```
$cars = [
    "toyota" => ["colors" => ["red","blue"]],
    "mazda" => ["colors" => ["red"]],
    "honda" => ["colors" => ["blue"]],
    "nissan" => ["colors" => ["red","yellow"]],
];
```

I need a function that will return all the cars that have a specified color.

I can do this using a foreach loop.

```
function getCarsByColor(string $color, array $cars){
    foreach($cars as $key => $car){
        if(!in_array($color, $car['colors'])){
          unset($cars[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $cars;
}
```

Just wondering if there's a more direct way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the data from mysql? If so you could do it in your query

Comment: That's a good point. It's actually Postgres. The cars object is stored inside another object, as jsonb, so how would filter this out when querying for it?

Comment: something like `Select car.name, color.name from car inner join color on color.idCar = car.id where color = 'yourColorByPreparedStatementHere'`

Comment: I don't think I can run that query on a jsonb. If the car attributes were stored in their columns then it would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses `array_filter()`

```
$red_cars = array_filter($cars, function($car) {
    return in_array('red', $car['colors']);
});
```

As a function

```
function get_cars_by_color(array $cars, string $color = '') {
    return array_filter($cars, function($car) use ($color) {
        return in_array($color, $car['colors']);
    });

}
```

`use()` passes a variable from the current scope into a closure functions scope.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing conceptually wrong with what you're doing. In this specific scenario, really your only two choices are 1) modify the array copy to remove unwanted entries (what you're doing now), or 2) create a new array with only-wanted entries. Take your pick, really. One thing I do notice:

```
if(!in_array($color, $car['color'])){
```

This might be a typo but based on your array definition there will be no index named 'color'.